# Unable to use values from a class into another class

Tags: python, class, class-variables

I am trying to grab the values from a class and use that particular value into another class. However I keep getting this error - `AttributeError: 'CustomNodeTranslator' object has no attribute 'start'`

Basically I am trying to get/transfer the values of `self.start` and `self.end` to be used into the `ChanFileExporter` class

I am not exactly sure why it is not working but when I applied this similar method in another portion of the code, it is working fine.

Any advises are greatly appreciated!

```
class CustomNodeTranslator(OpenMayaMPx.MPxFileTranslator):
    def __init__(self):
        OpenMayaMPx.MPxFileTranslator.__init__(self)
    def haveWriteMethod(self):
        return True
    def haveReadMethod(self):
        return True
    def filter(self):
        return "*.chan"
    def defaultExtension(self):
        return "chan"
    def writer( self, fileObject, optionString, accessMode ):
        self.start = []
        self.end = []

        for opt in filter(None, optionString.split(';')):
            optSplit = opt.split('=')

            if optSplit[1] == '0':
                startAnimation = cmds.findKeyframe(which='first')
                endAnimation = cmds.findKeyframe(which='last')
                self.start = startAnimation
                self.end = endAnimation

class ChanFileExporter():
    def __init__(self, transform, startAnimation, endAnimation, cameraObj):
        self.fileExport = []
        testClass = CustomNodeTranslator()

        mayaGlobal = OpenMaya.MGlobal()
        mayaGlobal.viewFrame(OpenMaya.MTime(1))

        startAnimation = testClass.start
        endAnimation = testClass.end


        for i in range(int(startAnimation), int(endAnimation + 1)):
            ...
            ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The first time you see `start` or `end` in `CustomNodeTranslator` is in the `writer()` method.

```
    self.start = []
    self.end = []
```

It is bad practice to add attributes outside of `__init__()`; and the reason why it fails for you is because you are referring to attributes that do not yet exist since they are created only **after** you call `writer()`.

Comment: I have managed to find a solution to my given issue and it is working fine (finally, after I have been doing the same code for some time now)!! Thanks!